# Añadir elementos a un array y eliminar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tengo un foreach con php que me muestra unos botones en los cuales puedo añadir unos colores, esos botones son para marcar y desmarcar.

```
var colores_elegidos = [];
var color = "";
var contador_colores = 1;

//Obtencion de colores
$("body").on("click",".info_color_conf", function(){
    var data = {};
    color = $(this).data("color");
    $('#color_elegido').html(color);
    //Si el color tiene la clase activa la borramos, si no añadimos cuantas queramos
    if($(this).closest('.activeProducto').length == 0){
        $(this).addClass('activeProducto');
        
        data.color = color;
        colores_elegidos.push(data);

        contador_colores++;
    }else{
        if(contador_colores > 1){
            $(this).removeClass('activeProducto');
            contador_colores--;
        }
    }
    console.log(colores_elegidos);
});
```

Cuando hago click en uno y luego en otros, etc... Me devuelve esto

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
 0: {color: 'Amarillo Fluor'}
 1: {color: 'Naranja Fluor'}
 length:2
 [[Prototype]]:Array(0)
```

El añadir a un arreglo me funciona bien, pero cuando pulso al mismo botón del color elegido quiero quitarlo del array, pero no se como hacerlo.

He probado con map, con find, etc.. pero no se como posicionar el color que pulso

Comment: Un comentario, la variable `contador_colores` diria que no la necesitas. Si necesitas saber cuantos colores han elegido podes usar `colores_elegidos.length`.

Comment: La variable `contador_colores` la tengo para que nunca descienda de 1, ya que al menos tienen que tener un color elegido

Comment: Insisto, eso lo podes saber usando `colores_elegidos.length`. Otro comentario mas... no estas controlando que no agreguen 2 veces el mismo color. Imagino que normalmente no debería suceder, peeero...

Comment: Probare lo que me dices, en el momento que le pulsan al mismo color, se borra del array, funciona como eliminar elemento

Comment: Mi segundo comentario apunta a lo siguiente: antes de agregar o quitar del arreglo, deberías ver si ya esta o no, eso nada más.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por qué no lo intentas con [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
Algo así:

```js
colores_elegidos = colores_elegidos.filter(item => item.color != color)
```